# R equivalent of Stata qfit

Tags: r, statistics

I want to add a non-linear regression line to a scatter plot in R. I've tried using the `predict()` command, but I have not been able to make it work for my data.
My friend is doing it in Stata, where `graph twoway qfit x y` yielded a curved line, as I wanted in R. Is there such a function in R?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Do you happen to know if I can upload a data set here, in some way? I don't know how to produce an example without that...

Comment: The link I provided gives suggestions for including data with your question. It doesn't have to be your actual data, just something we can easily use for testing.

Comment: @DespeRate did my solution work?

Comment: @leeum Yes! Sorry for not getting back yet, but yes, it worked marvelously! I have even been able to use that for a project I'm working on, so thank you for that!

Comment: @DespeRate great. Can you mark my answer as correct for future readers? Click the check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer using `library(ggplot2)`

You want to use `geom_smooth` in your data. I believe `method = 'gam'` will give you a curved line. So if you have this below:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_scatter(aes(x = xvar, y = yvar))
```

You need to just add

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_scatter(aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + 
geom_smooth(aes(x = xvar, y = yvar), method = 'gam')
```

See here for more info: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html